# Where does っぱい derive from?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, i-adjectives

As it says in the title, I'm hoping to find out where the adjective ending -っぱい comes from (like in 酸っぱい 'sour'). Is it related to -っぽい (X-like, X-ish) at all? I can't seem to find an etymology for it if there is one known, but I really only have access to free resources like wiktionary and anything I can find on a google search and isn't behind a paywall, and that hasn't brought up anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can find, the ～っぱい ending is peculiar to two words: しょっぱい and すっぱい.

[Shogakukan's 国語大辞典](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A1%A9%E3%81%B1%E3%81%84-2044894#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8) and [Daijirin](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A1%A9%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B1%E3%81%84-534958#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88) both suggest that the ～っぱい ending for しょっぱい is a shift from 映【は】ゆし ("blindingly bright"; as an auxiliary element, "to appear XX; to be conspicuously XX").  Digging around, I also found [Shogakukan](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%B9%B9%E6%98%A0%E3%82%86%E3%81%84-516930#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89), [Daijirin](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%B9%B9%E3%81%84-279480#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88), and [Daijisen](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%B9%B9%E6%98%A0%E3%82%86%E3%81%84-516930#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) entries for 鹹【しおはゆ】い, which appear to corroborate this derivation.

Separately, I suspect that the more-common ～っぽい suffix may also derive from this same 映【は】ゆし, although I cannot currently find any Japanese source that says anything more than simply that っぽい is from ぽい, and that ぽい is a suffix essentially meaning *-ish*, *-like*.

Comment: Oddly, I easily found one possible etymology for っぽい but っぱい had evaded me. Thank you.

Comment: @LinguistCat, do you have a link for the っぽい derivation?

Comment: Only through wiktionary,  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%81%84#Etymology which I now notice doesn't have a citation. Perhaps that was why it was easy to find. But if I see anything else backing it up I will comment again with the update.